# Playscape SDK. Failed to execute lib2dex

Tags: unity-game-engine, playscape

Unable to build the project with Playscape Publishing Kit v1.6 on a Windows 7.

> Failed to execture lib2dex. Error description: jar2dex
>   C:\Users\Win\AppData\Local\Temp\nd2zqels.0mc.jar ->
>   C:\Users\Win\AppData\Local\Temp\t8ubvyh6.bqq.\classes.dex call
>   com.android.dx.command.Main.main[--dex, --no-strict,
>   --output=C:\Users\Win\AppData\Local\Temp\t8ubvyh6.bqq\classes.dex, C:\Users\Win\AppData\Local\Temp\nd2zqels.0mc.jar]
>
> UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
>   Playscape.Editor.AndroidApkCreator:Jar2dex(String, String) (at
>   Assets/Plugins/Playscape/Editor/AndroidApkCreator.cs:229)
>   Playscape.Editor.BuildProcess:Build(String) (at
>   Assets/Plugins/Playscape/Editor/BuildProcess.cs:202)
>   Playscape.Editor.AndroidPostProcessor:build(Boolean, BuildCompleted,
>   BuildProgressChanged, BuildFailed) (at
>   Assets/Plugins/Playscape/Editor/AndroidPostProcessor.cs:44)
>   Playscape.Editor.AndroidPostProcessor:Run() (at
>   Assets/Plugins/Playscape/Editor/AndroidPostProcessor.cs:88)
>   Playscape.Editor.BuildProcessor:OnPostprocessBuild(BuildTarget,
>   String) (at Assets/Plugins/Playscape/Editor/BuildProcessor.cs:41)
>   UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

Comment: Vlad, We already have publishing kit version 1.15. Can you upgrade and see if the issue still exists?

Comment: solved. https://github.com/Playscape/Documentation/wiki/Solving-Error---Too-many-method-references---max-is-65536

Answer (score 1):

Try next:

1. Remove playscape sdk from your unity project:

   - /Assets/Plugins/Android/PlayscapeManifestFragments
   - /Assets/Plugins/Android/PlayscapePublishingKit
   - /Assets/Plugins/Playscape
   - /Assets/StreamingAssets
   - /Assets/Temp
2. Import new Playscsape SDK;
3. Try to build your project;
4. If issue reproducing remove `google-play-services` lib from unity and import it again and check that you have stripped `google-play-services.jar` correctly.(How to strip `google-play-services.jar` you can read [here](https://github.com/Playscape/Documentation/wiki/Solving-Error---Too-many-method-references---max-is-65536)).